# Anyone know what this wire sticking out of my wall is?

Tags: wiring, old-house

Moved into a new (but old) house recently and found this sticking out of my wall. Any idea what it is? Old telephone or radio wiring assembly?

[image]

Comment: First you drive your car into your new house, and then you plug that into the OBD-II port on the vehicle. ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That’s the cable and connector used between Verizon FIOS ONTs (mounted outdoors typically) and their indoors-mounted AC-DC power supply and backup battery.

The larger wires carry DC power (from either the AC supply or the battery); the smaller wires communicate status (power failure, battery missing, etc.) between the two units.

Comment: I should have recognized it!